# Write a text file using stream

Tags: java, file-io, path, writer

`reader = new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(
    "/apathdir/textFile.txt"), "UTF-8")`

Hi!

I have this `reader` and, basically, i want to do a `writer`, this way, save this file on same path of the jar file, like:

`>ls`
`>myJarFile.jar textFile.txt`

Comment: I don't think you can simply overwrite an entry in the jar you are running from.  A Jar is just a zip file, so you can probably recreate a zip file.  Why do you want to do it in the jar?  Why not on the filesystem in a directory you control?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./textfile.txt
```